# Controlling table at the beginning of a section

Tags: floats, positioning

I have a document, and there is a chapter with few tables. In this chapter I have this section:

```
\section{Some section}
\begin{table}[H]
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
---
\end{tabular}
\caption{Some caption}
\end{table}
```

now, after compiling I get section at the top of the page and my table at the bottom. I tried to use

```
\usepackage{float}
```

with H or h options for tables, and it worked for other tables, but not for this one. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi Andna, welcome to TeX.sx! You'll need to supply a more complete example. Can you make a small example document (starting from `\documentclass`) that reproduces the behaviour?

Comment: When I was editing the files to post it here, I tracked the error, I needed to add \newpage after the table (I have new section and image after the table), now everything looks as I want, thanks :)

Comment: Glad the problem's solved!

Comment: @Andna: `\clearpage` might be better here. Also see the  other questions about table/figure placement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I encounter such a "strange" behaviour, I add a paragraph between sections or chapters or -- here -- chapter and a tabular with just one command: `\mbox{}`. Usually that helps. And this seems better to me than a hard `\newpage` or `\clearpage`. You never know how long your tabular will become in the end and if it becomes longer than one page you will later wonder why TeX leaves a page blank except for one line.

Comment: @egreg The question is _not_ too localized, in the opposite: it is a _common_ problem that LaTeX creates a strange layout, if you have a page full of sections, maybe a float, _but no text_ ! And `\newpage`etc. isn't a good solution! So please reopen.

Comment: +1 As an anecdote that this is not too localized, I had this exact problem, and your answer solved it.

Comment: @BrianDiggs I'm very pleased to read that.